# Is there a way to change the spacing between tag items in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, ios13, xcode11

I created a new Xcode project from the 'Tabbed App' template using SwiftUI.
I would like to modify the spacing (margin or padding) between the tab items.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What you've already tried and what didn't work?

Comment: It let me add .padding() to the TabView but that takes the whole navigation bar and shrinks it. I tried to add .padding() to each individual .tagItem but it doesn't even build when I do that